# Nested tmux sessions on local and remote servers

Tags: nested, tmux

I'm trying to setup tmux to work like so:

- Outer session (level 0) on localhost with prefix C-a
- Inner session (level 1) on localhost with prefix C-b
- Inner session (level 1) on remote host with prefix C-b

So each inner session is nested directly in the outer session.

If I setup my `.tmux.conf` like this:

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
bind-key -n C-b send-prefix
```

the local inner session receives the `C-b` prefix properly, but remote inner session doesn't.

If I change my `tmux.conf` to this:

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
```

then the remote inner session receives `C-b`, but the local session doesn't.

Is there a way I can configure tmux so that both the local and remote nested sessions receive the `C-b` prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [this blog post](http://blog.htbaa.com/news/tmux-scripting) on Tmux scripting, I was able to find a solution.  I put this in my shell startup script (e.g. .bashrc) on my localhost:

```
tmux_outer() {
  SESSION=$1
  tmux -2 new-session -d -s $SESSION
  tmux set prefix C-a
  tmux -2 attach-session -t $SESSION
}

tmux_inner() {
  SESSION=$1
  env TMUX='' tmux -2 new-session -s $SESSION
}
```

and removed my .tmux.conf

The problem in my original .tmux.conf:

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
bind-key -n C-b send-prefix
```

seems to be `set -g prefix C-a`, which globally sets the prefix to `C-a`.  In my shell function, I create the outer session in a detached state, set the prefix to `C-a` only for that session, and then attach to that session.

When I start an inner session on my localhost or remote host, it has the default tmux prefix `C-b`.  Since the outer session isn't trying to capture and send `C-b`, both inner sessions receive `C-b` with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

tmux manual says, if I read it correctly, 1) prefix is server-level setting and 2) all sessions are managed by a single server. This means you can't get outer and inner session at the same host with different prefixes, unless you are starting multiple servers using corresponding options as non-default socket and another config for a second server.

Alternatively, it's easier to use GNU screen instead of tmux. It allows prefix specification in command line and unlimited server count in a easier way.

UPDATE[2017-07-05]: modern tmux has enough per-session configuration, including switch prefix, despite in somewhat cumbersome way.